# How to replace multiple values across multiple columns of a dataframe with NA

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, character, na

I am working with a large dataframe where each row is a study participant, and 20 of the columns are codes for the medications that they were prescribed. Here is an example, but in my data each row can have up to 20 ATC_code columns filled in.

```
dset <- data.frame("studynr" = c(1:10),
                   "ATC_code1" = c("B05XA02", "L01XC07", "B01AC05", "B01AE07", "C02AB01",
                                   "C03BA10", "C03BA11", " J01CF05", "R03DA11", "R06AE07"),
                   "ATC_code2" = c("V03AE07", "N06AB04", "N06AB10", "N06BX18", "H02AB09",
                                   "G04CB01", "C10AA01", "C08DA01", "C07AA07", "B01AA03"))

 studynr ATC_code1 ATC_code2
1        1   B05XA02   V03AE07
2        2   L01XC07   N06AB04
3        3   B01AC05   N06AB10
4        4   B01AE07   N06BX18
5        5   C02AB01   H02AB09
6        6   C03BA10   G04CB01
7        7   C03BA11   C10AA01
8        8   J01CF05   C08DA01
9        9   R03DA11   C07AA07
10      10   R06AE07   B01AA03
```

I have a large list of medications I want to exclude from my analysis, and hence replace all of their occurrences in the data with NA. In some cases I want to exclude entre medication classes (hence some of the exclusion codes are just the start of the full medication codes).
Here is a small example (my exclusion list is about 500 codes long):

```
exclude <- c("^C03", "^B05XA02", "^C07A", "^J")
```

How can I replace all the occurrences of my exclusion codes, across all 20 ATC columns, with NA all at once?

I have tried a few different ways to get this to work. Here's my latest attempt that seems to have created tens of thousands of tibbles....

```
exclude_fx <- function(x) replace_with_na(dset, replace = list(. = exclude))
dset <- apply(dset, 1, exclude_fx)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `exclude` vector already contains the regex for start of string (`^`), you can collapse the entire vector to separate the individual strings with `|`, so that we can use `grepl` to check the strings in your columns.

Wrap the operation in `across(starts_with("ATC"))` to act on all columns with column names starting with "ATC". Then a simple `ifelse` to assign `NA` to values matching `exclude`.

```r
library(dplyr)

dset %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("ATC"), 
                ~ifelse(grepl(paste(exclude, collapse = "|"), trimws(.x)), NA, trimws(.x))))

   studynr ATC_code1 ATC_code2
1        1      <NA>   V03AE07
2        2   L01XC07   N06AB04
3        3   B01AC05   N06AB10
4        4   B01AE07   N06BX18
5        5   C02AB01   H02AB09
6        6      <NA>   G04CB01
7        7      <NA>   C10AA01
8        8      <NA>   C08DA01
9        9   R03DA11      <NA>
10      10   R06AE07   B01AA03
```

Since some of your strings have leading white space, I used `trimws` to remove them while matching the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Function for cleaning multiple NA values

https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1972

```
na_codes <- function(x, ...) {
  x[x %in% c(...)] <- NA
  x
```